# Unable to login to Docker registry on Artifactory

Tags: docker, artifactory

I am able to get a token with:

```
(base) ➜  ~ curl artifactory.example.com/artifactory/api/docker/null/v2/token -u myusername:mypassword
{"token":"mytoken","expires_in":3600}
```

However when I try to login:

```
(base) ➜  ~ docker login artifactory.example.com -u myusername -p mypassword
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: Get http://artifactory.example.com/v2/: error parsing HTTP 404 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>404 Not Found</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Not Found</h1>\n<p>The requested URL /artifactory/api/docker/null/v2/token was not found on this server.</p>\n</body></html>\n"
```

It's like it's trying to do `http://artifactory.example.com/v2/artifactory/api/docker/null/v2/token` when it should be doing `http://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/api/docker/null/v2/token`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registry API requires that it is at the root of the url, and will not work under a path based reverse proxy. You need to allocate either a port or hostname to the docker API that responds to a request for `/v2` on that hostname. Artifactory implements this by giving you a [reverse proxy config generator](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/HTTP+Settings#HTTPSettings-DockerReverseProxySettings).

Comment: I am confused because I already have a reverse proxy for artifactory.example.com -> JFrog UI that uses *.example.com cert. Do I need to set up a second reverse proxy for docker.artifactory.example.com with *.artifactory.example.com cert?

Comment: Does `artifactory.example.com/v2` go to the docker registry API? If not, then you need another entry in the reverse proxy.

Comment: artifactory.example.com/v2 -> JFrog UI/v2, so not docker/v2 - I see, I think I understand now...

Comment: @atkayla on one side, it would be nice if the docker registry API worked under a path in a server. But the solution other registries use is to expose different ports. The artifactory solution of giving you a proxy configuration is nonintuitive.

Comment: Ok so OpenShift deploys Artifactory with Nginx reverse proxy, and I don't know how to configure that one. So I deployed a second Apache reverse proxy with second wildcard cert for *.artifactory.example.com just for the Docker registry at docker.artifactory.example.com and it worked! https://github.com/RedHatOfficial/openshift-artifactory-apache-reverse-proxy

Answer (score 1):

How is your example.com is setup? For me it looks like you are using the repository path as docker access method here. From the error it seems that the docker client got a HTML response instead of a response from Artifactory. It looks like the request did not reach Artifactory at first. Kindly share if any reverse proxy is on top of the example.com?
If possible, directly test it out with the IP as "docker login 12.23.34.45:8081" and let us know if this helps. If the login is successful then the issue is with the reverse proxy being used here. Share the reverse proxy logs and configs to look into it.

Comment: Yes, I am using repository path. Yes, it got an HTML response/did not reach Artifactory first. I am running on OpenShift using Artifactory Operator, it seems to use Nginx reverse proxy.

Comment: Artifactory Operator uses Nginx reverse proxy as in artifactory.example.com -> JFrog UI. I chose repository path instead of sub domain (docker.artifactory.example.com) because I don't have a wildcard cert, so I am trying to access my docker registry at artifactory.example.com, but I think it might be pointing to JFrog UI instead? So do I to deploy a SECOND reverse proxy to sit in front of the docker registry?